# Problems with PHP GD library when installing Typo3

Tags: php, typo3, content-management-system, gd

When I want to install the CMS TYPO3, following problems get detected:

1. PHP GD library true color support broken
   GD is loaded, but calling imagecreatetruecolor() fails. This must be fixed, TYPO3 CMS won't work well otherwise.
2. PHP GD library gif support broken
   GD is loaded, but calling imagecreatefromgif() fails. This must be fixed, TYPO3 CMS won't work well otherwise.
3. PHP GD library png support broken
   GD is compiled with png support, but calling imagecreatefrompng() fails. Check your environment and fix it, png in GD lib is important for TYPO3 CMS to work properly.

When I search for PHP GD2 in my apache server I can only find GD without the 2 - ist this a problem?
There are also some yellow colored problems - do I also have to fix these?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when running the latest wersion of XAMPP as it include PHP v8.
I installed an older version of XAMPP with php v 7.4.13 and the problem seems gone.